# Render base64 image from dataURL in Ruby and send back image

Tags: javascript, ruby, base64, html2canvas

So I'm really new to Ruby but I want to get something similar working to this tutorial where I pass over a canvas as a base64 encoded image and it sends back a png to download.

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2013/1/9/downloadable-svg-in-png-format

I need to do this for IE9 support but I can't get the code example from the above tutorial to work and I don't know enough about Ruby to figure it out.

Here's the front end javascript.

```
pushToServer: ()->
  html2canvas([$(".hidden_container")[0]],{
    onrendered: (canvas)=>
      strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL()
      @temp_container.children().remove()
      @temp_container.hide()

  $.ajax
    url: '/svg/create'
    data: {svg: "#{strDataURI}"}
    dataType: 'json'
    type: 'POST'
    success: (response, status, xhr) =>
      window.location.href = "/downloadable/" + response.id + '.png'
    error: (response, status)=>
      console.log response
})
```

and the ruby code

```
# routes.rb
  match "downloadable/:id(.:format)", :to => 'svg#show'

# svg_controller.rb
class SvgController < ApplicationController
  require "base64"

  def show
    @svg = Svg.where(id: params[:id]).first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.png {
        headers['Content-type'] = 'image/png'
        headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"chart.png\""
        @result = Base64.decode64(@svg.content.gsub('data:image/png;base64,', ''))
        render :text => @result
      }
    end
  end
end
```

To me it looks as if I need a ruby route to route the initial post request from /svg/create to somewhere but I don't really know how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need another Action to receive the request from the Javascript, add this to your route:

```
match "/svg/create", :to => 'svg#show'
```

I'm not really sure of what `#{strDataURI}` really is, but it must be the encoded canvas in base64, the decode only occurs on the show action, so the only thing you have to do in create is check that the parameters `svg` is given, a create a new record with it:

```
 def create
   return if not params[:svg]
   svg = Svg.create(content: params[:svg])
   render :json => svg
  end
```

I don't know if there are other field in your SVG model, if not, this code might work !

Comment: Thanks  for the reply. I'm getting this error though  "NameError (uninitialized constant SvgController::Svg):" Any idea what it means, or what I'm missing?